# Eclipse doesnt find android classes

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problems with importing Android platform classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785607/problems-with-importing-android-platform-classes)

I have errors in code that uses android classes, they cannot be resolved to a type. I've installed android sdk, adt plugin, avd manager. How I should to setup build path to make my project see android classes?

Comment: yes, for example android.support import cannot be resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is only classes in android.support you have to put android-support-v4.jar in your libs folder.
It is the support library.